# How to handle ClassCastException in java

Tags: java

I have a base class and a derived class. The code I am writing is

```
class Base {
    ...
}

class derived extends base {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        derived d = (derived) new Base(); //throws a ClassCastException 
    }
}
```

How is this handled? I would like to call the base class methods without the use of super keyword.

Comment: `Base` is not a `Derived` so it cannot be cast to `Derived`

Comment: ... while `Derived` is a `Base` so it can be casted to `Base` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Base class is a super class and derived class is subclass. You can not catch object of super class in reference of subclass.

```
Base b = new Derived();
```

Above instruction will work but

But following will not work.

```
Derived d = new Base();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the methods of the superclass without the use of super.

Base:

```
public class Base {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }

}
```

Derived:

```
public class Derived extends Base {...}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Derived d = new Derived();
    d.print();
}
```

Prints out:

`Base`

Answer (score 0):

actually 'Base' is not 'Derived', so casting is not possible.

it would have been possible in following case

Base b = new Derived()
Derived d = (Derived)b;

Answer (score 0):

Downcasting is not possible in java. It is only possible when base class stores the reference of derived class

```
Base b = new Derived()

// Check is required. It may lead to ClassCastException otherwise
if (b instancof D)     
    Derived d = (Derived) b;
```